# In tcsh how can I prepend 'cd ' to the output of a pipe?

Tags: pipe, tcsh

As in, say I execute `pwd` to return the current directory and want to dump this in a script file so that I can come back, but I then need to prefix it with 'cd '?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you are asking here.

Maybe you could try something like this?

```
echo cd `pwd` > /tmp/file
```

Comment: I was messing around with `awk` & pipes.  Doh.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

In case you're trying to accomplish this:

```
cd -
# Changes directory to the last one you were in
```

or

```
pushd and popd
# Push current directories on a stack with pushd
# Pop them back out (change to them) with popd
```